# How to smear without grease pencil and use paint texture effect styles like the cartoons in Looney Tunes? (Not for 2d character, only 3d character)

Tags: rendering, texturing, modifiers, node-editor, video-sequence-editor

Would anyone know how to do this without a grease pencil, only by using FXs or something for smearing like in cartoons? Also, painting textures on the smear. I always want to match the style of cartoons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for you?

Comment: sorry im late actually, i didn't not know all about this, but maybe you could show me a picture to explain how you'd make it? i am no expert at blender.

Comment: Just found this video ["Multiples" smear effect in Blender 3](https://youtu.be/Iih8usPqpOY). The method is described here is to duplicate parts of the mesh, degenerate (remove parts) and deform them, and make them visible only in certain frames to exaggerate the impression of movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CG productions will use deformations on fast actions to get a stylized impression of motion blur.  If you want to emulate the drybrush look from your examples, then you might try a hybrid approach.

---

Let's take Fudd from your second image as a case study.
I'd deform the character's head and upper body into the necessary smear area.
I'd then create some images of paintbrush strokes and alpha-map them onto planes of geometry that are deformed in front of the thing that is moving rapidly.
It's a bit labor-intensive for two or three frames, true, but probably simpler than trying to automate it.

[edit: adding a sample]
[image]

Download or create something like the drybrush stroke in this image.
Applied to the Alpha of the Principled Shader, you get a free-floating smear.  Deform this object in the shape needed and find a way to animate it onto the scene.  It could scale up from zero to sweep on left-right or you could even animate it on a spline path.  These blurs go so fast, you could probably just do a shape morph, pushing the vertices by hand.

Nickelodeon's "...Ninja Turtles" show did a lot of motion effects with the turtle's weapons, which would spin and swing at high speeds.  Frame-stepping in those, you'll see lots of bent or curved mesh deformation to get the right sense of speed.

All of that said, I think painting it in photoshop or Krita in post is probably the way to have the most control.  Doing it in 3D could be more of a hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Great,! thanks.